# Generalization of lower semicontinuous functions to Banach space-valued functions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, definition

Recall a definition of lower semicontinuous function (taken from [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-continuity#Formal_definition)).

> Suppose $X$ is a topological space, $x_{0}$ is a point in $X$ and $f:X\to \mathbb {R} \cup \{-\infty ,\infty \}$ is an extended real-valued function.
>   We say that $f$ is lower semi-continuous at $x_{0}$ if for every $\epsilon >0,$ there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x_{0}$ such that $f(x)\geq f(x_{0})-\epsilon $ for all $x$ in $U$ when $f(x_{0})<+\infty $, and $f(x)$ tends to $+\infty$  as $x$ tends towards $x_{0}$ when $f(x_{0})=+\infty$. Equivalently, in the case of a metric space, this can be expressed as
>   $$\liminf _{x\to x_{0}}f(x)\geq f(x_{0}).$$

My question is whether we have a generalization of the definition above to Banach space-valued functions.
More precisely,

> Let $E$ be a Banach space and $X$ be a topological space.
>   Then we say that $f:X\to E$ is **lower semicontinuous** at $x_0$ if for every $\epsilon>0,$ there exists a neighbourhood $U$ of $x_0$ such that $\|f(x)\|\geq \|f(x_0)\| -\epsilon$ for all $x\in U$ when $f(x_0)<+\infty.$

Does the definition above make sense?

Comment: You are just defining $f$ to be l.s.c. if the real valued function $\|f\|$ is.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Under the new definition, does it imply that sum of lower semicontinuous functions is again lower semicontinuous?